# How to remove a virus?

Tags: windows-10, virus

Windows Defender reported a virus on my PC: Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl. Avast reported another: Win32:Conduit-F. How can I check if the virus is running? I did not find any suspicious entries in LOCAL MACHINE (and CURRENT USER) Microsoft Windows CurrentVersion Run / RunOnce.

Answer (score -1):

http://fixpcviruses.com/trojan-win32-varpes-m-cl-removal/

**STEP1** :　Uninstall all unwanted and suspicious programs from computer control panel

**How to Remove from Windows 7**

1. Go to Start > Control Panel.
2. Open “Uninstall a program” under “Programs” group.
3. Select the program you want to uninstall from the list and choose “Uninstall/Change”.

[image]
**STEP2**: Remove all unwanted and suspicious add-ons, extensions, plug-ins from web browsers

**How to Remove from IE**

1. Open the desktop, and then tap or click the Internet Explorer icon on the taskbar.
2. Tap or click the Tools button , and then tap or click Manage add-ons.
3. Under Show, tap or click All add-ons, and then select the add-on you want to delete.
4. If the add-on can be deleted, you’ll see the Remove option. Tap or click Remove and then tap or click Close.

[image]

**STEP3** :　Go to C drive, find out all malicious files generated by Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl and then remove them manually.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl .exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl\
C:\ProgramData\TEMP\Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl.exe
C:\Users\your user account\AppData\Roaming\Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl.sys
```

**STEP4** :　Open Registry Editor (Press Win key and R key together, type Regedit in the Run Box, and then hit Enter) >>look for registry entries related to Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl and delete them manually.

```
KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run "[random].exe"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\[ Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl]
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppDataLow\Software\ Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl character
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\BrowserHelperObjects\[random numbers]
```

There is a second method listed on the website at

http://fixpcviruses.com/trojan-win32-varpes-m-cl-removal/

But it involves downloading spyhunter, and I cannot vouch for spyhunter because I have never used it before, so do so at your own risk.

Comment: It isn't clear what is your own original words and what is from "fixpcviruses.com".  You should edit your answer to make that clear.  *Once you do that I will reverse my vote.*  **You literally just copied and pasted, and failed to quote the material, which means you have not cited the material.**